# how do i make 1 function do multiple things

Tags: javascript, html, function

i currently have a code with 3 buttons and 3 functions
HTML:

```
<input type="number" id="a">
<input type="number" id="b">
<input type="number" id="c">

<button class="table" onclick="a()">-</button>
<button class="table" onclick="b()">+</button>
<button class="table" onclick="c()">*</button>
<center><p id="demo"></p>
```

javascript:

```
    <script>
function a(){
    var a = document.getElementById("a").value;
    var b = document.getElementById("b").value;
    var c = document.getElementById("c").value;
    var d = a-b 
    if (c == d){
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML="bravo la reponse est" + d;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML="faux la reponse est" + d;
    }
}
function b(){
    var a = document.getElementById("a").value;
    var b = document.getElementById("b").value;
    var c = document.getElementById("c").value;
    var d = Number(a)+ Number(b) 
    if (c == d){
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML="bravo la reponse est" + d;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML="faux la reponse est" + d;
    }
}
function c(){
    var a = document.getElementById("a").value;
    var b = document.getElementById("b").value;
    var c = document.getElementById("c").value;
    var d = a*b 
    if (c == d){
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML="bravo la reponse est" + d;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML="faux la reponse est" + d;
    }
}
    </script>
```

i would like it if sombody would help and make it more compact using only 1 function if possible
thank you

Comment: Ok so you can use destructing to define your variables in one line instead of three. You can use turnery operator for your if statements to make them more readable, and you could use document.querySelectorALL('.tabel') to get a node list and then use, .forEach() to apply your function to each of the elements / quick note here: if your gonna have multiple table classes, give them another class called math or somthing so they stand out. Take a look at these points online - write your solution using them and if its not working let me know and I will check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a function to the function

```
function f(fx){
    var a = document.getElementById("a").value;
    var b = document.getElementById("b").value;
    var c = document.getElementById("c").value;
    var d = fx(a, b); 
    if (c == d){
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML="bravo la reponse est" + d;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML="faux la reponse est" + d;
    }
}
```

and use it in your HTML:

```
<button class="table" onclick="f(function(a, b) { return b - a; })">-</button>
<button class="table" onclick="f((a, b) => Number(a)+ Number(b))">+</button>
<button class="table" onclick="f(function(a, b) { return b * a; })">*</button>
```

Or to keep your HTML cleaner you can create 3 functions from a base function:

```
function f(fx){
    var a = document.getElementById("a").value;
    var b = document.getElementById("b").value;
    var c = document.getElementById("c").value;
    var d = fx(a, b); 
    if (c == d){
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML="bravo la reponse est" + d;
    } else {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML="faux la reponse est" + d;
    }
}
function f1() { return f(function(a, b) { return b - a; }); }
const f2 = () => f((a, b) => Number(a)+ Number(b));
const f3 = function() { return f(function(a, b) { return b * a; }); };
```

and use them in your HTML:

```
<button class="table" onclick="f1()">-</button>
<button class="table" onclick="f2()">+</button>
<button class="table" onclick="f3()">*</button>
```

It is more readable with lambdas but some browser don't support lambdas. Therefore I showed both ways.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<body>
    <input type="number" id="a">
    <input type="number" id="b">
    <input type="number" id="c">
    <div id="op">
        <button class="table" >-</button>
        <button class="table" >+</button>
        <button class="table" >*</button>
    </div>
    <center><p id="demo"></p></center>
<script>
    function calc(signal,a,b) {
        a = Number(a);
        b = Number(b)
        switch (signal) {
            case '-':
                return a - b
            case '+':
                return a + b
            case '*':
                return a*b
            default:
                throw new Error('signal mistake')
                break;
        }
    }
    document.getElementById('op').addEventListener('click', (e)=>{
        var a = document.getElementById("a").value;
        var b = document.getElementById("b").value;
        var c = document.getElementById("c").value;
        let signal = e.srcElement.innerText;
        let d =calc(signal, a, b)
        if(c == d) {
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML="bravo la reponse est" + d;
        } else {
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML="faux la reponse est" + d;
        }
    })
 </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use objects method, the following will use button text as symbol

```js
let calculate = {
  "-": (a, b) => a - b,
  "+": (a, b) => Number(a) + Number(b),
  "*": (a, b) => a * b
}

function check() {
  let inputs = document.querySelectorAll('[type="number"]');
  let symbol = event.target.textContent;
  let result = calculate[symbol](inputs[0].value, inputs[1].value);
  let text = result == inputs[2].value ? "bravo la reponse est:" : "faux la reponse est: ";
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text + result;
}

document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach(button => button.onclick = check)
```

```css
input {width: 70px}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="a"> (?)
<input type="number" id="b"> =
<input type="number" id="c">

<button class="table">-</button>
<button class="table">+</button>
<button class="table">*</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```